# Algolia Autocomplete Images & URLs are Incorrect - Magento2

Tags: magento2, algolia

My search results page images and URLs are leading to "localhost" instead of my domain (opulentjewelers.com) on my Magento2 install. The issue only exists on the instantsearch page -- the shop pages and Algolia autocomplete dropdown all lead to the correct URLs. Any idea why this issue is occurring? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In the Algolia, there are indexed URLs with `localhost` domain. In order to change it, you need to reindex your catalog from the production environment, not your local one.

If you use both environments and you're reindexing data from both of them, make sure you have set a different index prefix for each environment:
[image: Index prefix setting]

For example, on your local Magento instance you can have prefix `magento_dev_` and in production you can use `magento_prod_`. Having different index prefixes makes sure that the extension won't target the same indices and therefore override your production data (titles, prices, URLs, images, ...) with development data.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jan. Unfortunately, I've changed my Index Prefix, made sure the new indices were being actively used, reindexed my algolia tables on magento, and cleared cache, but the images are still pulling from localhost. Am I missing a step?